# Deployment Status lists Scheduled batch Jobs (as succeeded)

Tags: deployment, scheduled, status, jobs

I have created a batch to run at 10 minute intervals (6 jobs for each 10 mins of the hour, using CRON string). The batches run fine, but they also show up in the Deployment Status as succeeded each time they are executed.

I am not able to find a reason for this, so far.

How do I avoid this from appearing in the Deployment status? Appreciate any help in this regard.[image: Scheduled Jobs listed in Deployment Status]

Comment: Is the batch using the [Apex Metadat API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata.htm) to make changes to layouts or custom metadata type instances?

Comment: @Phil W: Yes, it does update Metadata API. Now I get it why it lists in deployments. Thanks. I suppose there is no way to avoid this, except switching to Custom Settings against Custom Metadata.

Comment: Why would you want to switch to custom settings? These are a special type of data, not metadata, and thus cannot be deployed and may be missing on a (non-full) sandbox created from production. Additionally list custom settings are deprecated in favour of custom metadata types. Plus you can define page layouts for CMT which you cannot for custom settings.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of merits and demerits of Custom Metadata. The client doesn't want a deployment listed every ten mins. And the scenario did not demand custom mdt and a list type custom setting was sufficient. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, it's your client not mine (but I would be telling them to live with it since to use a list custom setting is to use a deprecated Salesforce feature).